# Is the sum of a mixture of (non-centred) gaussians subgaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, concentration-of-measure

Consider independent random variables $X_i$ each with density given by

$f_{X_i}(x) = \frac{\phi}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_i^2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \frac{(x - \mu_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}} + \frac{1 -\phi}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_i^2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \frac{(x + \mu_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}}$

where $\phi \in (0, 1)$, $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i^2 = 1$, $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i = \mu \neq 0$, $\mu_i > 0$. Notice that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = (2\phi -1) \mu_i$.

**Question**: How tightly does $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ concentrate around its mean? Is $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i]$ subgaussian? Or at least sub-gamma or sub-exponential? (See pages 24-30 of Gabor Lugosi's *Concentration Inequalities* textbook).

My attempt: Computer simulations indicate that it might be at least sub-gamma.
In an attempt to use the Chernoff bound, I calculate:

$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i]} \right] = e^{-\lambda (2\phi - 1) \mu} \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\phi e^{\lambda^2 \sigma_i^2/2 + \lambda \mu_i } + (1-\phi) e^{\lambda^2 \sigma_i^2 / 2 - \lambda \mu_i} \right) = e^{\lambda^2/2-\lambda (2\phi - 1) \mu} \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\phi e^{\lambda \mu_i } + (1-\phi) e^{- \lambda \mu_i} \right)$

but I can't upper bound this to look like a subgaussian mgf. I have also tried showing the sufficient condition that $\mathbb{E}[X^{2q}] \leq q!C^q$ (see Theorems 2.1 and 2.3 of Lugosi's *Concentration Inequalities* book) but have not succeeded in obtaining a tight enough bound. I have obtained a $\mathbb{E}[X^{2q}] \leq 2q!(2(\sigma_i + 2\phi \mu_i)^2)^q$ bound, but this is loose and implies no concentration around the mean as the subgaussian proxy grows just as fast.

For reference:

**Subgaussianity**: Suppose random variable  follows the inequality:

$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}] \leq \exp(\lambda^2 \sigma^2 / 2)$,

then we say that X is $\sigma$-subgaussian.

Comment: Are the $\mu_i$ all non-negative?

Comment: If so, I would have thought the tails for $|x|> \mu$ must be between the tails of $N(\mu,1)$ and $N(-\mu,1)$, So they have Gaussian decay.

Comment: Yes, all $\mu_i$ non-negative. Edited.

Comment: That intuition seems on the right track. But because the mean of $X_i$ is not $\mu$, I am unable to show that it has a tail with only slight $\mu$ dependence.

Comment: The mean of $X$ is $(2\phi-1)\mu$ so anywhere in $[-\mu,\mu]$ depending on $\phi$.  If $\phi=1$ then the tails are the same as the tails of $N(μ,1)$ while if $\phi=0 $ then the tails are the same as the tails of $N(-μ,1)$.  In other cases somewhere between the tails of the two Gaussians.  If $0 \le \mu \ll 1$ then the two bounding pairs of tails will be close to each other while if  $\mu \gg 1$ they will be far apart but both still Gaussian